# Automatically rename _s theme (batch search & replace text)

Tags: regex, perl, find, replace, xargs

I just started using the [_s wordpress theme](https://github.com/Automattic/_s), and the instructions there say

> The first thing you want to do is copy the _s directory and change the
>   name to something else. Like, say, megatherium. Then you'll need to do
>   a three-step find and replace on the name in all the templates.
>
> 1. Search for `_s` inside single quotations to capture the text domain.
> 2. Search for `_s_` for to capture all the function names
> 3. Search for `_s` with a space before it to replace all the occurrences of it in comments. (You'd replace this with the capitalized version of
>      your theme name.)
>
> or ...
>
> ```
> Search for:'_s'  Replace with:'megatherium'   
> Search for:_s_   Replace with:megatherium_   
> Search for: _s   Replace with: Megatherium
> ```

so I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /path/to/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ -type f | xargs perl -pi -e "s/'_s'/'mytheme'/g"
find /path/to/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ -type f | xargs perl -pi -e "s/_s_/mytheme_/g"
find /path/to/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ -type f | xargs perl -pi -e "s/ _s/ mytheme/g"
```

using perl to perform the inline search/replace on all the files, however this messes something up and returns a 500 error when I try to view my wordpress.

Is there a better way to perform a search & replace on the text of a group of files? one that won't bork my php?

**EDIT**

I'm running this on OSX Lion...

when I use `find ./mytheme -name \*.php -type f -exec php -l '{}' \;` It shows that there aren't any syntax errors anywhere.

**EDIT 2**

After asking this, and running it a couple of times on fresh copies, it's working. Extra eyes are like mojo for fixing things via telepathy.

Comment: "this messes everything up" - specifically, what is messed up?

Comment: For the syntax check, try `find ./mytheme -name \*.php -type f -exec php -l '{}' \;`  This will run `php -l` on each of the files one at a time, unlike `xargs` which will pass all the filenames as parameters to the same command.

Comment: Thanks, @IlmariKaronen, that's much better, to use `xargs` like I had it should be `find ./mytheme -name \*.php -type f | xargs -n 1 php -l` (I was missing `-n 1`) but why pipe when you don't have to?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the commands you used to do the search and replace shouldn't work.  Have you checked your server logs to see what's causing the 500 errors?

Comment: um... it works now... wtf. thanks for everyone's time, your mojo solved the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, all of the text tokens you are trying to replace are either:

1. the text token `_s`, or
2. a token that begins with `_s_`

So `'_s'` and `_s_setup()` should be replaced, `get_s` and `_substr()` should not. The assertion `\b`, to match a "word-boundary", could be helpful here.

```
$ find /path/to/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ -type f | \
    xargs perl -pi -e "s/\\b_s\\b/mytheme/g"


$ find /path/to/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ -type f | \
    xargs perl -pi -e "s/\\b_s_/mytheme_/g"
```

will probably get you closer to where you want to be.